# 555 timer question

Tags: timer, 555

[image]

R1=500k variable resistance
R2= 10k 
when the timer's operation time is 5sec, R1 86.7k
What is the operation time when 4V is applied to 5(red point)?

im student, so I would very appreciate it if you could explain it in detail

Comment: Do your own homework . But note that without the 4v applied you have 5v x 10k/15k at this node instead ...

Comment: The trick is simple - to connect a perfect voltage source (4 V) in parallel to an imperfect voltage source with some internal resistance (5 V and the top 5 k). As a result, the perfect voltage source will dominate with its voltage (4 V). So, without 4 V applied, the voltage divider (3 × 5 k) produces 5.2/3 V (high threshold) and 5.1/3 V (low threshold). When 4 V is applied, it will produce 4 V and 4.1/2 V. You will have to do the rest yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the first order RC differential equation at pin 5, and you’ll arrive at your solution.

4V = 5V * (1-exp(-t/RC))

Where, R = R1+R2

t = RC*ln(5)
t = 7.31 seconds